# Get admin menu to show features that a role has permission to

Tags: 8

I have a few client roles I have created.  They have permissions around creating and editing content mostly.  In the admin, their menu is small -- clicking Manage only provides Content.  This works well.  However, I have tried to also grant one role permissions to manage webforms and entityqueue.  These pages are under the Manage > Structure menu.  I can't seem to get the menu to show to allow access to Manage > Structure > webforms or Manage > Structure > entity queue.

Is there a permission I am missing to get these to show in the menu?

Comment: Did you flush the cache?

Comment: Check if "Use the administration pages and help" permission is on for those roles.